# Automatic properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating an application using Backbone which follows the structure below:

```
App = {
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Collections: {},
  Routers: {}
};
```

When designing an object – in this case, a View –, I do the following:

```
App.Views.ProductsView = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

But, I want something like:

```
App.Views.Products.IndexView = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

**What's the big deal?**

If I previously declare `App.Views.Products = {}`, everything will work – but I want to do it automatically; without any previous declaration.

Based on my problem, can you give me an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I get it, but you have declare the property before you can add properties to the chain ?

```
App.Models.Products = {};

App.Models.Products.IndexView = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

Of course, you could declare it in a number ways, for instance when you create App

```
App = {
  Models      : {
        Products : {} // here
  },
  Views       : {},
  Collections : {},
  Routers     : {},
  Views       : {}
};
```

or as a literal containing the key etc

```
App.Models.Products = {
    IndexView : Backbone.Model.extend();
}
```

---

As an answer to the edited question, ***you can't***, javascript has no magic methods to create missing properties, you have to declare them yourself.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - There is no way to do that, the missing property will always throw an error. You could create some sort of convenience method that takes a set of properties and checks if they are defined, but that would be more complicated and add so much crap to the way you declare properties, it's not worth it.

Comment: Get it. Thank you for this clarification! By the way, if I "host" `Products` on the `App` scope, I won't access `App.Models.Products`, but `App.Products` instead.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - That's right, my mistake, I've changed it!

Answer (score 0):

> If I previously declare App.Views.Products = {}, everything will work
>   – but I want to do it automatically; without any previous declaration.

If you only want to create the object in case you need it, a common way to create objects on the fly is:

```
App.Views.Products = App.Views.Products || {};
```

This way you don't need to create the object in advance.